# Ideas for manual copy-paste from excel to python code in spyder

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I often work with excel sheets of which I want to copy just one specific column of numbers into my python script for plotting purposes. This has to be done manually since it is always a different file, columns and rows.

To use numpy arrays, I need the data with a trailing comma to create a python array in this way (I had to add spaces, otherwise stackexchange would post it in a line):

```
myArray=np.array([
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    6
)]
```

So after copying the column with the numbers from excel, I have to add the commas manually. If I have a lot of data, I'll add a column in Excel where I add alle the commas and copy the numbers with the commas together. However I feel like there should be a better way to do this.

Do you guys know a way that python might swallow my data without commas? E.g.

```
myData = someFunction(
   1
   2
   3
   4
   6
)
```

Or do you have another Idea how to add the commas more elegant? I'm using Spyder with Python 3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:  If the requirement is to copy one column or row and not a grid. `in_` below can be used with replace to produce a comma separated string.

```
# First copy a column from a spread sheet to the clipboard.
# in_() will return the values separated by newlines '\n'. 
# replace these by comma
in_()
# Out[21]: '3\n13\n23\n33\n43\n53\n63\n73\n83\n93\n103\n113\n123\n'
in_().replace('\n', ',')
# Out: '3,13,23,33,43,53,63,73,83,93,103,113,123,'

# If copying a row the copied separator is tab '\t'
# Copy a row in a spreadsheet
in_()
# Out: '60\t61\t62\t63\t64\t65\t66\t67\t68\n'    
in_().replace('\t', ',')[:-1] # [-1] removes the newline character.
# Out[25]: '60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,6'
```

I wrote the `in_()`and `from_grid()` to copy data from spreadsheets into variables I wanted to use in my python terminal.  They let a user copy a region in a spreadsheet to the clipboard.  `in_()` will return the clip as a string. `from_grid()` will return this converted to a list of lists of strings.

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

def in_():
    """
    Returns the contents of the clipboard as text.
    Usage:  txt = in_()
    """
    clip=tk.Tk()
    clip.withdraw()
    temp=clip.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
    clip.destroy()
    return temp

def from_grid(delimit_row="\n", delimit_cell="\t"):
    """
    Returns a list of lists copied from the clipboard.
    Usage:  grid=from_grid(delimit_row="\t", delimit_cell="\n")
        grid is a list of lists 
        [  [ r00, r01, r02, ... ],
           [ r10, r11, r12, ... ],
            ....
        ]
    by defaut:  the row delimiter is a newline, "\n"
                the cell delimiter is a tab character, "\t"

    This will paste a copied region of a spreadsheet into a list of lists.
    """
    txt=in_()
    rows=txt.split(delimit_row)
    ret=[]
    for row in rows:
        temp=row.split(delimit_cell)
        ret.append(temp)
    return ret[:-1]  # A final empty last row is appended.
                     # This loses it.

import numpy as np

def to_floats( data ):
    result= []
    for row in data:
        temp = []
        for item in row:
            temp.append(float(item))
        result.append(temp)
    return np.array(result)

arr = to_floats( from_grid() )
```

This doesn't do exactly what you've asked for but gives a way of getting the spreadsheet data into python where it can be processed.

Running this in a python console will let the user print the results, which can then be copied into a script.

There may be neater ways to do it.  There are some Libraries around, Pyperclip is one but I've never used it.

Comment: Thanks! That's probably the best way to do it. I am opening your script once in spyder and let it run. After that, the spyder console knows about the function and I create the desired output by typing in_() in the console. Then I copy the output into my script. :)

Comment: It sounds like you could write a function using `in_` above to capture the paste operation and produce a plot rather than copy/paste the rsult into a script to produce the plot.

Comment: In my case, I need to save the data together with the plotting script in case I want to change the graph later. It's for my thesis.