# Tkinter spreadsheet data entry

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tkinter

I'm not quite sure the best way to ask this (I've tried searching and can't find what I'm looking for). I have a GUI that uploads an excel sheet that has base information, cleans it up, adds in relevant information, and exports out a new excel.

What I'm looking to do is to be able to copy/paste the relevant data directly into the GUI rather than uploading an excel sheet. The data is on a different application that currently has to be pasted into an into an excel sheet to be able to be uploaded.

For reference the data would be 3 columns and up to 100 rows in length.

Let me know if more information is needed or if I can explain something better! I'm very new to programming so I'm not always sure what verbiage to use.

Update: This is my script currently. I was looking to replace def getExcel1 () with being able to paste the information over rather than having to paste into an excel then upload the excel.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import pandas as pd
import xlwt


window = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(window, width = 400, height = 250, bg = 'lightsteelblue2', relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(window, text = 'Store Name', width = 20)
entry1 = tk.Entry()
canvas1.create_window(250, 100, window = entry1)
canvas1.create_window(100, 100, window = label1)


def getExcel1 ():
    global df1
    
    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    df1 = pd.read_excel (import_file_path)
    
browseButton_CSV1 = tk.Button(text="      Import TC56 Information   ", command=getExcel1, bg='green', fg='white', font=('bookman old style', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 50, window=browseButton_CSV1)


def getInput1 ():
    global df2
    
    df2 = entry1.get()

submit_button1 = tk.Button(text = 'Submit Store Name', command = getInput1, bg = 'green', fg = 'white', font= ('bookman old style', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 150, window = submit_button1)


def CreateExcel ():
    Serial = df1['DSN'].str.split('S').str[1]
    Asset = df1['Asset']
    DevNum = df1['Device #']
    Friendly = df2 + ' ' + '#' + DevNum.astype(str) + ' ' + Serial.astype(str)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Serial': Serial, 'FriendlyName': Friendly, 'Asset': Asset, 'ProdOG': df2 + 'AD'})
    export_file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.xls')
    df.to_excel (export_file_path, index = None, header=True)
    

browseButton_CSV1 = tk.Button(text="      Create Input File   ", command=CreateExcel, bg='green', fg='white', font=('bookman old style', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 200, window=browseButton_CSV1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61256050/ideas-for-manual-copy-paste-from-excel-to-python-code-in-spyder/61259471#61259471) do the sort of thing you need.  It reads from the system clipboard into a python variable.

Comment: That might work but I'm not quite sure how to get it joined into my program. I tried replacing my import file function with the in_() function he had listed there and made the temp be a global variable but when running the script I got an error saying it wasn't defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The in_() function reads and stores text from the clipboard.  It also assumes there's no tk.Tk() object so it's not really needed here.  It's the from_grid function that arranges the text into nested lists.  You may prefer to arrange for it to return a dataframe rather than a list of lists.

I've trimmed your code to just show the reading part.  I've no real pandas experience.  I think there may be ways to read into a pandas dataframe from the clipboard but I've never done it.

**To use:** copy a region in an excel spreadsheet before clicking "Import TC56 Information" The resulting dataframe will print in the console.  It can then processed as required.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

window = tk.Tk()

def from_grid(parent, delimit_row="\n", delimit_cell="\t"):
    """
    Returns a list of lists copied from the clipboard.
    Usage:  grid=from_grid(delimit_row="\t", delimit_cell="\n")
        grid is a list of lists 
        [  [ r00, r01, r02, ... ],
           [ r10, r11, r12, ... ],
            ....
        ]
    by defaut:  the row delimiter is a newline, "\n"
                the cell delimiter is a tab character, "\t"

    This will paste a copied region of a spreadsheet into a list of lists.
    """
    txt = parent.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD") # Replaces the in_() function.
    rows=txt.split(delimit_row)
    ret=[]
    for row in rows:
        temp=row.split(delimit_cell)
        ret.append(temp)
    return ret[:-1]  # A final empty last row is appended.
                     # This loses it.


canvas1 = tk.Canvas(window, width = 400, height = 250, bg = 'lightsteelblue2', relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()

df1 = 0 # Result store

def do_paste():
    global df1
    temp=from_grid( window )
    df1 = pd.DataFrame( np.array( temp[1:] ), columns= temp[0] ) # Assumed column headers from Excel
    print(df1)  # To see what's happening remove once it's working

    
browseButton_CSV1 = tk.Button(text="      Import TC56 Information   ", command=do_paste )
canvas1.create_window(200, 50, window=browseButton_CSV1)

window.mainloop()
```